# How to find root-cause of: urllib2.URLError: <urlopen error [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:590)?

Tags: python, ssl, certificate, ssl-certificate, urllib2

I'm trying to test an API to `breezometer.com.` When I enter my API key into the web-page `https://breezometer.com/api/` it returns the expected JSON reply.

However, entering exact same data - in the following python script that mimics the web request (from both Python 2 and 3):

```
$ cat test2.py
#!/usr/bin/env python

"""
Location from Google Maps: https://www.google.co.il/maps/place/Haifa+Port,+Haifa/@32.8267212,34.9852862,15z/data=!4m2!3m1!1s0x151dbbcd3a79ff47:0x8d20ff1e4833b549?hl=en

request: https://api.breezometer.com/baqi/?lat=32.8267212&lon=34.9852862&key=API_KEY
"""

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2

latitude = 32.8267212
longitude = 34.9852862
api_key = "XXXXXfb123e242839edeb10539dXXXXX"

url = "https://api.breezometer.com/baqi/?lat={0}&lon={1}&key={2}".format(latitude, longitude, api_key)

print(BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen(url)))
```

I get:

```
$ python test2.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test2.py", line 18, in <module>
    print(BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen(url)))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 154, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 431, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 449, in _open
    '_open', req)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 409, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 1240, in https_open
    context=self._context)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 1197, in do_open
    raise URLError(err)
urllib2.URLError: <urlopen error [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:590)>
```

I've looked at similar SO threads (e.g., [Python 'requests' [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:590)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32745309/python-requests-ssl-certificate-verify-failed-certificate-verify-failed-s) et al from https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=_ssl.c%3A590+CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED)

I've imported `https://breezometer.com/api/` and `https://breezometer.com/` certificats (in all available formats) to Chrome - following https://stackoverflow.com/a/31627786/1656850 advice: still, I'm getting CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED error.

**Any suggestions how to debug this issue?**

Comment: It makes no sense to import the certificates into Chrome if the problem is with python, because python does not use the certificates from Chrome.  Instead you need to use the capath parameter for urlopen.

Answer (score 0):

With Python 2.7 add verify=False i.e.

```
requests.get(url, headers=user_agent, verify=False)
```